# How to configure Jenkins master and dynamic agents in different clouds? With Kubernetes plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, azure-devops, ibm-cloud, devops

For context, I work at a large company with teams in different clouds (Azure and IBM cloud formerly Bluemix). The Ops team will have control of Jenkins master eventually, but since my team is the first needing this, we are setting it up.

What we have:

- Jenkins master is in Azure (**cloud A**), latest version, and we have the Kubernetes plugin (among others) to have dynamic provisioning of agents.
- My team works in IBM Kubernetes clusters (**cloud B**). In this cloud, we have a namespace for devops in a cluster of k8s, where we want the slave agents to be created and run. In this cloud we also created a service accounts in that namespace, a role, and rolebinding.

Problem: Configuring Jenkins master to connect with such namespace in IBM cloud to provision agents and run the jobs as needed. 
Especifically, in Jenkins > Manage > COnfigure System > Cloud.
Here I have:

- Kubernetes URL set to the IP:port of the master node of the cluster
- Kubernetes server certificate key, I put here the certificate I got when I created the service account.
- Namespace, Credentials I have the service account and finally the Jenkins URL.

When I try that configuration, and test the connection I get:

> Error testing connection https://ip:port: Failure executing: GET at:
>   https://ip:port/api/v1/namespaces/devops/pods. Message: Unauthorized!
>   Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may
>   have been revoked. Unauthorized.

Questions:

- Anybody knows how to do this or has links to something similar?
- In the image, what should I put in kubernetes URL? According to the docs, I should enter the container engine cluster endpoint, what is that in IBM Cloud? I have the IP and port of the Master node.

I´ve read a lot of documentation from IBM, the kubernetes plugin for Jenkins (https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) and tons of other posts explaining how to configure jenkins with kubernetes and dynamic provisioning and many of them said it is possible to have jenkins and the slaves in different clouds, but none of them explained how to do it..

Thank you in advance.

++++++++++++++++++ UPDATE +++++++++++++++++++++++

In the following screenshot I show the configurations that I am using. In particular, the fields **Kubernetes URL** and **namespace**.

Thanks to @samhain1138 for his help so far, but **I cannot get a connection test successful** in the Jenkins Kubernetes plugin configuration section. I think I may not be entering the correct info in some of the fields in that section.

Note: Please keep in mind that my setup is as follows: Jenkins master is in Cloud A (Azure) and I want the agent nodes to run is in a different cluster in another cloud, call it Cloud B (which in my case is IBM Cloud).

[image]

In the screenshot above I am certain that I have the correct values for the **Kubernetes URL** and **namespace**, but I am unsure about the other fields (**Kubernetes server certificate key** and **Credentials**.)

In the **Kubernetes server certificate key** field I tried putting:

- The ca.cert of the Service Account in the kubernetes cluster in IBM. (Obtained by 1. creating service account, getting the secret of that service account, and extracting the ca.cert from such secret)
- The "Token" from the server, which I get doing a kubectl config view in the kubernetes cluster in IBM. The token is in the field users>user>auth-provider>config>id-token when you execute the command "kubectl config view"

In Credentials I created and tried different **Kinds**:

- Username and Password: I tried this with my credentials for the IBM cluster and with the service account credentials (When I created the service account, role, and role-binding, I noticed that user was created which was serviceaccountname-namespace-cluster)
- Kubernetes Service Account

I tried all the combinations of those, and could never get **Connection Successful when Testing the Connection**.

Erros I get:

- Error testing connection https://APISERVER: Failure executing: GET at: https://APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/a-devops-namespace/pods. Message: Unauthorized! Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. Unauthorized.
- Error testing connection https://APISERVER: Failure executing: GET at: https://APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/a-devops-namespace/pods. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list pods in the namespace "a-devops-namespace".

Comment: What did you try with service accounts and what service account are you using?

Comment: @Rico in the namespace of the cluster I plan tu run the slaves, I created a serviceAccount, a role, and bind it with rolebinding. I got the ca.cert of its secret and put it in Jenkins > kubernetes server certificate key.

Comment: @Alo you didn't explain the error very well; what's throwing the error? Is that when the **Jenkins master** on **cloud A** tries to open a connection to the **Kubernetes master** on **cloud B**? In which case the service account must be configured on **cloud B**, not **cloud A**

Comment: Hi @samhain1138, I will edit the question in a min, but to answer your question, yes that is exactly what I mean and I did. I have Jenkins in cloud A (azure), and a cluster and namespace ready in cloud B (IBM). I got a serviceAccount, role and rolebinding in cloud B, and put the certificate of that in the configuration of jenkins (in cloud A) section kubernetes, and when I tried to test the connection I got that error message.

Comment: @Alo how did you create the service account on cloud B? Is RBAC enabled on cloud B?

Comment: @samhain1138 I put the yamls I used here: https://gist.github.com/alothings/eff42a3a33834e16cf0321886ec2c826
Cloud B for me is IBM Cloud, according to the docs when I create the service account and roles I am stating to use rbac, am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: @Alo thanks, that allows me to answer your question. If it does solve your problem, please accept the answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you'll need to change a few things in the Jenkins master **UI** which if I understand correctly runs within your Azure account.

First of all, the Jenkins master is trying to connect to the local (Azure) Kubernetes master.
You'll have to set it to something that resolves to the Kubernetes master running on IBM.
For for that matter, the hostname will **not** end with ".local".

I doubt the credentials you're using in the screenshot you posted correspond with the Kubernetes master on IBM (they correspond to the Azure Kubernetes master, otherwise you'd get a different error), so you'll need to update those, as well.
This is covered [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/), and when you're done, [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/configuring-jenkins-kubernetes-engine#adding_kubernetes_credentials) (under "Then, set up the HTTP credentials by following these steps", ignore the gcloud command used to fetch the password).
Make sure the Kubernetes master on IBM is accessible **from** the Jenkins master on Azure using the "test connection" button.

Then you also seemed to confuse the Kubernetes namespace setting.
Your service account uses the `devops` namespace while your Jenkins master is configured to use the `kubernetes-plugin` namespace.
Service accounts correspond to namespaces so you'll want to update that setting to `devops`.

This is still an extremely bad idea, especially in terms of security (if I sniff your connection I can copy and use your IBM k8s master's password + service account, which allows me to launch pods!).
You really should be running that Jenkins master on IBM, or if you have a good reason for this weird setup, at least make sure this connection goes over a VPN...

Comment: Thanks! I am trying what you said now.Though I should point out that screenshot is from a tutorial, for security reasons. In my case the kubernetes URL is the IP and Port of the master node of IBM, and I modified the yaml I uploaded, the namespace is not devops :). I will update as soon as I completely test your response!

Comment: @Alo oh, okay, I had no way to know that, but it was still important to emphasize. Good luck, and please update or accept the answer! :)

Comment: I´m sorry to say that this didn´t work for me.
The 1st link you shared "Access Clusters using k8s API" I used the section "without kubectl proxy" I got the APISERVER which I use in the Kubernetes URL. 
And the 2ndlink, said to use my credentials http credentials assume the ones for the IBM Cluster and didn´t work either.
I am going to edit the question showing all the things I have tried, hope it helps.
I did check I can access the IP and port using a website that validates that. Error message is: "pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list pods in"

Comment: @Alo I saw the update, I don't understand anything, I'll need you to describe everything in better detail

Comment: I have just modified the update. I hope this helps. My issue right now is that I get error when testing the connection in the Jenkins configuration page, and I believe I am not using either the field "Kubernetes server certificate key" or "Credentials" correctly. I tried the HTTP kind but was not successful, even though my credentials have admin privileges in the IBM k8s cluster.

Comment: @Alo I'm afraid I give up, either explain yourself much better, wait for someone else to help you, move the Jenkins master to IBM, or hire professional help. Sorry, your explanation is not clear, which feels disrespectful of my time

Comment: I have been asking what is it that you find confusing, I can´t clear up something I don´t know is confusing. Anyway, thanks for trying.

Comment: @Alo first, update the screenshot of your Jenkins configuration. Then, I understand you don't want to show the IP, but I have no way of telling which IP it is (Azure Kubernetes master, IBM Kubernetes mater, something else?). There are no credentials set in the screenshot, what kind of credentials? For which cluster? Please be very specific about each and every detail